# How to redirect to specific url assigned to index number in python

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import sys
import re
from tabulate import tabulate

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.iimbx.edu.in/dashboard')

user_input = driver.find_element_by_id('login-email')
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

user_password = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
user_password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[4]/button')
button.click()

res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

courseSection = soup.find_all("section", { "class" : "mycourse_grid_sec" })
courseList = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'})
courseinfo = soup.find_all('h2', {'class':'mycourse_title'})

print('list of courses in your dashboard:')

coursesDict = []
# for i in range(0, len(courseinfo)):
#     courseAnchorTag = courses.find('a', href=True)
#     coursesDict.append({'number': i,'title': courseAnchorTag['title'],'href': courseAnchorTag['href']})


i = 0
for courses in courseinfo:
    i = i+1
    courseAnchorTag = courses.find('a', href=True)
    courseTitle = courseAnchorTag['title']
    courseLink = courseAnchorTag['href']
    coursesDict.append({'number': i,'title': courseTitle, 'href': courseLink})
    print(f'{i}: {courseTitle} : {courseLink}')
```

/// The output for the above statement is as follows:

```
list of courses in your dashboard:
```

> 1: Accounting and Finance :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMB+EEP_AC104x+EEP_AC104x/course/ 2: Strategic
>   Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST101x+082019EEP/course/ 3:
>   IIMBx Awards : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+Awards101+2019_T3/course/ 4:
>   Strategic Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST101x+IBA2019/course/
>   5: Accounting and Finance :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC104x+102018EEP/course/ 6: People Management
>   : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+042019CR1/course/ 7: People
>   Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+0918CR1/course/ 8: People
>   Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+0718CR1/course/ 9: People
>   Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+022019CR1/course/ 10:
>   Introduction to People Management :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+0917BL1/course/ 11: Customer
>   Relationship Management :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+MK210x+0917AC1/course/ 12: Customer
>   Relationship Management :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+MK210x+0817BL1/course/ 13: Accounting and
>   Finance : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC104x+0817EEP1/course/ 14:
>   Customer Relationship Management :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+MK210x+0817EEP1/course/ 15: People Management
>   : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+HR101x+0817EEP1/course/ 16: Introduction to
>   Accounting - 1 : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC101x+0817EEP1/course/ 17:
>   Strategic Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST101x+0817CR1/course/
>   18: Strategy and the Sustainable Enterprise for Teachers :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST250x+0817FD1/course/ 19: Introduction to
>   Banking & Financial Markets :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+FC201.1x+1017_AC1/course/ 20: Predictive
>   Analytics : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+QM901x+0917AC1/course/ 21: DO
>   Your Venture : Entrepreneurship for Everyone :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+EP101x+0817AC1/course/ 22: Management
>   Accounting for Decision Making :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC102x+0817AC1/course/ 23: Introduction to
>   Marketing Essentials : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+MK101+0817CR1/course/
>   24: Introduction to Accounting - 1 :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC101x+2017_R2/course/ 25: Introduction to
>   Banking & Financial Markets :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+FC201.1x+2017_T2/course/ 26: Banking,
>   Financial Markets & Systems (PGP) :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+FC201+2017_T2/course/ 27: DO Your Venture:
>   Entrepreneurship for Everyone :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+EP101x+Instructor-paced/course/ 28:
>   Organizational Design: Creating Competitive Advantage :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+OB102x+Instructor-paced/course/ 29: Strategic
>   Management : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST101x+Instructor-paced/course/
>   30: Introduction to Managerial Economics :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ES101x_R1+2017_T2/course/ 31: FDP -
>   Introduction to IIMBx MOOCs :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+FDP001x+2017_T2/course/ 32: Introduction to
>   Accounting - 1 : /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC101x_R1+2017_T2/course/
>   33: Introduction to Accounting - 1 :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+AC101x+Instructor-paced/course/ 34:
>   Introduction to Managerial Economics :
>   /courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ES101x+Instructor-paced/course/

///

```
chosen_no = int(input('Please enter the Course Number '))
```

///  when I print the above statement I got input box which say to enter the course number.

/// After I entered it is not redirecting how to do that I don't know any code help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please attach some actual code you've written, and show what you've tried already.

Comment: Hi blueteeth, just now I updated the code in which username and password is not mentioned as it is private information. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Please sort out the list of courses so it's a readable format. Where are line breaks supposed to be?

Comment: i have sorted and given line breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get the 'href' based on index.

```
lt = [{'number':1,'title':'Accounting and Finance :','href':'/courses/course-v1:IIMB+EEP_AC104x+EEP_AC104x/course/'},
        {'number': 2, 'title': 'Strategic Management :',
         'href': '/courses/course-v1:IIMBx+ST101x+082019EEP/course/'},
        {'number': 3, 'title': 'IIMBx Awards :',
         'href': '/courses/course-v1:IIMBx+Awards101+2019_T3/course/ '}
        ]
chosen_no = int(input('Please enter the Course Number '))

print ([x for i,x in enumerate(lt) if lt[i]['number']==chosen_no][0]['href'])
```

Result:

```
Please enter the Course Number 1
/courses/course-v1:IIMB+EEP_AC104x+EEP_AC104x/course/
```

Comment: Sir each user has different courses in his dashboard, every time I can't do the above function. So, is there anything that will do it automatically. And the courses which you are seeing here are for one user if I log in using another user then the dashboard courses and links are different

Comment: To do that your list 'lt' should consist of only the courses which are visible to the user. Rest of the code will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
chosen_no = int(input('Please enter the Course Number you want to Extract: '))
selectedCourse = 0
i = 0
for course in  coursesDict:
    if course['number'] == chosen_no:
        selectedCourse = course

    i = i+1

print(selectedCourse)
driver.get('https://your_site_url' + selectedCourse['href'])
```

Please try this